# wordpress user roles are not working

Tags: users, user-roles, user-access

I have never assigned or used a role before on this site, I have just created a new user role with plugin "user role editor" and also assign an editor Role to other account, whenever I log in with editor role or custom Role it keeps on redirect to website but no admin page,

I tried with 3 plugins now to gave them access, check wordfence as well if that's the reason

but no solution to it,

I am unable to see admin dashboard except administration role

please help

Comment: I would deactivate the plugins that add/modify the roles and login with native Editor role. This will show you if the issue is tied with some of the plugins. After that activate them one by one and see which on will cause the issue again. Last step is to see if the plugin has settings page and look for an option that might force the redirection. If you feel confident in your programming skill I will answer with a code snippet for a new role.

Comment: I had to copy administrator capabilities and create are roles then restrict the options which I don't want to provide to that role via plugin name "adminimize"
solved my issue though.